# remove specific folder and files on remote machine

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I need to remove all the files from specific folder that is copied to remote machine using following command:

```
tar -c test_sandy | ssh sky@my_home_vm 'tar -xf - -C /scratch/backup'
```

I see all the files from test_sandy has been copied to remote machine, now I wanted to remove these files after say one minute:

```
ssh my_home_vm find $backup_path/test_sandy/* -type d -mmin +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

But I don't see those file getting deleted, but if, I run the delete it directly from remote machine (instead doing "ssh my_home_vm") it worked.

Comment: `$backup_path` is being evaluated on the local system, not on the remote server. Does using `find /scratch/backup/test_sandy/` (no * is necessary) change the process?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have forgot to put braces for command after ssh:

```
ssh my_home_vm 'find $backup_path/test_sandy/* -type d -mmin +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;'
```

And also **$backup_path** env variable may not be set when trying to run cmd from ssh, so you can try using the full path.
Hope this helps.